# Can LuaLaTeX make wrapping text around figures easier?

Tags: luatex, wrap

If there is one thing LaTeX has never been good at, it is wrapping text around figures. Well, I have grown used to LuaLaTeX always providing a solution to what seemed impossible before. **So does there exist some effective LuaLaTeX solution to wrapping text around figures?**

Comment: In ConTeXt it seems to work correctly, so wether it's with TeX macros or with Lua code, it *seems* that LuaLaTeX can actually make that wrapping easier.

Comment: Then it might be worth turning it into a LaTeX package. I don't see a Lua-based package on the market at the moment.

Comment: I doubt lua would help much (you have to set the parshape lengths in anycase, whether you do the calculations in lua or tex) The question is asking to be closed as "too broad" really, it would help tie it down if you gave a specific example of a case where wrapfig does not do what you want.

Comment: `wrapfig` causes troubles near the end of pages and near lists. It is a quite well-known problem that is also mentioned in the manual (as far as I remember).